# Show that a linear surjective map is interior (open mapping) iff exists constant c s.t. ||x|| <= c||y||

Tags: functional-analysis

This is an exercise from "Analysis for applied mathematics"

Show that a linear surjective map $L:X \to Y$ is interior if and only if there is a constant c such that for each $y \in Y$ there is an $x \in X$ satisfying $Lx = y$, $\lVert x\rVert \le c\lVert y\rVert$.

Can someone point out a direction for solving this? BTW, I did not find how to type the "surjective mapping" arrow.

Comment: Consider an open set $U\subseteq X$. Fix $x\in U$, and let $y = Lx$. Now, let $y'\in B(y,r)$ (later on you will have to pick a particular radius). By surjectivity, there is $x' \in X$, such that $Lx' = y'$. What can you tell about $\|x'-x\|$?

Comment: So $\lVert L(x'-x) \rVert < r$, How can I extract $x$ from $Lx$ ?

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ Banach Spaces?

Comment: @DavidBowman, No, $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily be Banach space

Comment: Use the assumption: $\|x\| \leq c\|Lx\|$.